# python: how to add a key-value pair to the beginning of a nested dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested, ordereddictionary

i need to add to the beginning of a nested dictionary. it looks like move_to_end() is the easiest way for us to accomplish this but it seems that i cannot use this in a nested dictionary.

```
dict = OrderedDict({
  'abdomen' : {"liver":3 , "spleen":1},
  })
dict['abdomen'].update({'stomach':'2'}) 
dict['abdomen'].move_to_end('stomach', last = False)
print(dict['abdomen'])
```

generates the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 232, in 
    dict['abdomen'].move_to_end('stomach', last = False)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'move_to_end'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner dictionary must be an `OrderedDict`. Change to the following:

```
my_dict = OrderedDict({
    'abdomen': OrderedDict({"liver": 3, "spleen": 1}),
})
```

Note: Using built-in names (e.g., `dict`) is a bad idea. Change `dict` to something suitable.